# AngularJs PluginCall

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Below code is service code that makes connection to the server in a phonegap project. Please help me to make it a plugin call.
I am using this format for calling the server : pluginname.http.sendRequest(success, error, url, methodtype);

```js
app.service('server', function ($state, $http, RequestData) {
    this.httpPost = function (postdata, urlvalue, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        if (urlvalue != 'HeaderData') {
            RequestData.reset();
        }
        //----------------
        //--------------
        //--------------

        $http({
            methos: 'POST',
            url: urlvalue,
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
                    'Pragma': 'no-cache'
            },
            data: postdata
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (successCallback != null) {
                successCallback(data);
            }
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            routeToError(data, status, errorCallback);
        });
    };
```

Comment: format your code before posting question

Comment: If you want to post data on server then no need to any plugin, you can use simple jquery ajax call in angularjs.